How to interpret t-statistics in a regression with constraints on coefficients?
Suppose I have an OLS regression, the most generic form.
$z = a + b*x + c*y$
And I have one additional constraint that sum of the coefficients is 1. i.e. $b+c =1$.
Here I have a couple of question on the t-statistic reported by common statistic packages after imposing the constraint $b+c=1$.
Question 1: Do statistic packages report the t-stats for the constrained regression? Say suppose the statistic package tells me that $b=0.7$ and $c=0.3$, do they tell me the t-stats for $b$ and $c$?
Question 2: How to interpret the result if they do?
Suppose I am told that $b=0.7$ and $c=0.3$, and $t(b) = 4$, and $t(c) = 0.1$, does it mean that $c$ can be omitted from the model? My confusion is that $b$ and $c$ are estimated together under the constraint that $b+c=1$. Seems omitting $c$ is not an option now?
Thanks for any help!

Change of variables : $$\begin{cases} Y=z-y\X=x-y\end{cases}\quad\implies\quad Y=a+b:X$$
